# What is the max longest database name in tdengine?

Tags: tdengine

Just like the title, I tried to create a database in tdengine, but I meet a DB error throw by Taos shell. Which said that “invalid operation:name too long”.
Does anyone know the max length of database allowed in tdengine? Is this is configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Database name: cannot contain "." and other special characters, and cannot exceed 32 characters.
More info, you can refer [taos.cfg](https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/administrator#config)